# mongodb $addtoset guaranteed to add to end of array?

Tags: mongodb

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-%24addToSet

Although it's not specifically said in the documentation, I presume
this operation will always add the element (if unique) to the end of an
array and never any other position. True statement?

Also asked on mongodb-user http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user/browse_thread/thread/c342758081466312?pli=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

Under the hood it currently does, but that behavior is not in spec and should not be relied upon. $push adds to the end of the array.

Answered via Eric Horowitz in mongodb-user http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user/browse_thread/thread/c342758081466312?pli=1

Comment: Looking at this answer four years later, I'm questioning why I thought something with "set" in the name would make any guarantees about ordering.